# Outlook add in On-Send event is firing

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

Im trying to get a simple function to append some data to the mail body using the on-send function.

in my manifest file, I have this setting the extension point

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
    <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="setItemBody" />
</ExtensionPoint>
```

my javascript is taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

```
function validateBody(event) {
    console.log('validateBody');
    item.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
}

// <param name="asyncResult">MessageSend event passed from the calling function.</param>
function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(asyncResult) {
    var listOfBlockedWords = new Array("blockedword", "blockedword1", "blockedword2");
    var wordExpression = listOfBlockedWords.join('|');

    // \b to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b.
    // i to perform case-insensitive search.
    var regexCheck = new RegExp('\\b(' + wordExpression + ')\\b', 'i');
    var checkBody = regexCheck.test(asyncResult.value);

    if (checkBody) {
        mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Blocked words have been found in the body of this email. Please remove them.' });
        // Block send.
        asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
    }

    // Allow send.
    asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}
```

But when i hit send on the email i just keep getting 'The add-in has prevented this item from being sent.'

and looking in the browser debugger i cannot see that it has written out the console.log in the validateBody event.

Any body any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As an update to this, as I have now solved it, its due to where the called function (in my case setItemBody) resides in your Function.js (or what ever is set as your function file)

The method being called by the ItemSend needs to be at the very root, even before the Office.initialize function. This at least solved it for me as I found it by reading this article https://theofficecontext.com/2017/06/12/the-most-anticipated-officejs-feature-is-here/